# Docker registry on EKS using service account to store data on S3

Tags: amazon-s3, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, docker-registry

I'm trying to configure docker registry v2 on a EKS cluster. I'd like to use S3 as storage backend with credential manage by service account but it seems that doesn't work.
I log in running POD to check permissions using:

- aws sts get-caller-identity
- aws s3 ls s3://BUCKET_NAME
- aws s3 cp s3://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME
- aws s3api put-object --bucket BUCKETNAME --key KEY

and all seems to work properly but if I try to perform a "docker push" I get this error log:

s3aws: AccessDenied: Access Denied\n\tstatus code: 403

If I set ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY it works but I'd like to use service account.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> If I set ACCESS_KEY and SECRET_KEY it works but I'd like to use service account.

Yes, in Kubernetes you use Service Accounts. But the AWS API requires IAM Permissions for authorization.

You can setup [IAM Roles for Service Accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts.html) to associate a Kubernetes ServiceAccount with an IAM Role. You also need to add the needed IAM Permissions to that IAM Role. Using aws-cli or and AWS SDK should work with that solution from a Pod.

Comment: I setup IAM Roles. If I try to install AWS CLI and execute, for example, `aws s3 cp` command from inside the POD it works.

If I execute `aws sts get-caller-identity` I have:

`{ "UserId": "XXXXXXXXXXX:botocore-session-XXXXXX", "Account": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::XXXXXXXXXXX:assumed-role/ROLE/botocore-session-XXXXX" }`

Comment: You need to provide credentials to docker. See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/authenticating-amazon-ecr-repositories-for-docker-cli-with-credential-helper/

Comment: I'm execute docker registry as a registry server so I don't need to provide docker credential. Is docker client that have to provide credential to reverse proxy NGIX.

This works fine because I'm able to login to docker registry. Only when it's necessary to access to S3 that docker registry generate access error.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you can run aws CLI commands without getting any error messages means that your service account is setup properly and it can use those permissions but it doesn't mean all applications running on that pod can use them too. Your application (in your case docker registry) should use a AWS SDK version that supports assuming an IAM role via OIDC web identity token file. you can see the list of supported SDK versions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/iam-roles-for-service-accounts-minimum-sdk.html)